# Jenkins pipeline for build multi configuration projects

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have played around with jenkins pipeline and like it a lot.
Our team has a project which follows structure described below

```
A         ->     B      ->      C
Debug            Debug          Debug
Release          Release        Release
```

Basically, project C depends on project B and project B depends on project A. When we mark A as a successful build, it has to pass both debug and release build. LKGB is marked as a project that does not break either debug or release build.

I wonder how can we translate this logic into pipeline code, building debug and release are more like "Sub Projects" since they run on different machine".

I tried using "parallel jobs" but it will make the debug/release output mixed together.

I tried out the "multi config" plugin and it serves our need, is there an equivalent version for jenkins pipeline?

Comment: What do you mean by "parallel jobs"?  Can you give an example or two of why your pipeline looks like?

Comment: I guess I should say "parallel steps" as it is the term pipeline uses, basically it is like "paralles { Debug: {buildForDebug} , Release: {buildForRelease}}"